# How to recover variables from another page php

Tags: php, mysqli, header, location

I would like to pass variables from a "start.php" page to a "question.php" page knowing that:
the variable in question was retrieved on the page "verificationcode.php" by the method $ _POST.
How to retrieve category and level variables?

In "start.php":

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" id='signin' name="signin" action="verificationcode.php">
 <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
 <select class="form-control" name="level" id="level" style="width=66%">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="codeact" id="codeact" value=""  placeholder=" Enter your code" required />
```

In "verificationcode.php":

```
if($_SESSION['email'] !== "")
{
    $email= $_SESSION['email'];
    if (isset($_POST['codeact'])&& isset($_POST['category'])&& isset($_POST['level']))
        {
            $codeact = $_POST['codeact']; 
            $category= $_POST['category'];
            $level=$_POST['level'];
            if($codeact !== "" && $category !== "" && $level !== "" )
            {
                $query = "SELECT codeactivation FROM user where email ='".$email."'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                    { 
                         $codeactivation=$row['codeactivation'];
                    }
                if($codeactivation==$codeact)
                {
                    $category= $_POST['category'];
                    $level=$_POST['level'];
                    $user = $_SESSION['email'];
                    echo $category;
                    echo $level;
                    echo $user;
                    mysqli_query( $conn,"UPDATE user set category_id='$category' , level_id='$level' where email='$user'") or die(mysql_error()); 
                    header('Location: question.php?category=$category,level=$level');

                }else
                {
                    header('Location: startexam.php?erreur=1');
                    echo "Erreur";
                }
            }
        }

}
```

In "question.php":

```
 if(isset($_GET['category'])&& isset($_GET['level'])){
                $category = $_GET['category'];
                $level=$_GET['level'];

            }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YzbR.png)

Comment: What is the problem? You already seem to be doing that...

Comment: @jeroen ,in "question.php" the variables "category" and "level" are unknown(undefined variable).How to recover these two variables in "question.php"?

Comment: You have 2 empty, unclosed, `select` elements. Is this your real html code?

Comment: @jeroen,No it's just to inform you a name of these variables

Answer (score 0):

On question.php page use this:

```
$_GET['category'];
```

Comment: category query string value is visible on url ??

Comment: yes,it is visible but incorrect: .../question.php?category=$category,level=$level